# Does Morley's congruence characterize primes greater than $3$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, congruences

In 1895 Morley showed that $$\binom{p-1}{(p-1)/2}\equiv(-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}4^{p-1}\pmod{p^3}$$
for any prime $p>3$.

In 2009, I formulated the following conjecture concerning the converse of Morley's congruence.

**Conjecture**. If $n>1$ is an odd integer satisfying the Morley congruence
$$\binom{n-1}{(n-1)/2}\equiv(-1)^{(n-1)/2}4^{n-1}\pmod{n^3},$$
then $n$ must be a prime.

I have verified the conjecture for all odd integers $1<n<10^4$.

**QUESTION**. How to solve the above conjecture? Can one find a counterexample?

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: Is there any reason why the congruence holding modulo $n^2$ rather than $n^3$ wouldn't be enough to force $n$ to be prime?

Comment: I agree with Mike, and even better, modulo $n$ only for prime powers ? Maybe this hints to a proof.

Comment: For the prime $p=16843$, the Bernoulli number $B_{p-3}$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $p$. If we take $n=16843^2$, then $$\binom{n-1}{(n-1)/2}\equiv(-1)^{(n-1)/2}4^{n-1}\pmod{n^2}.$$

Comment: L. Carlitz [Canad. J. Math. 5(1953), 306-316] showed that for any prime $p>3$ we have $$(-1)^{(p-1)/2}\binom{p-1}{(p-1)/2}\equiv 4^{p-1}+\frac{p^3}{12}B_{p-3}\pmod{p^4}.$$

Comment: I've tested the conjecture for $n$ below $10^6$.

Comment: Max, thank you very much for the check.